# Reading Property from a file using PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer inside a method of a spring managed bean

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using below code to read a file, i can read the values defined in the `env.properties` using the `@Value` annotation ( Injection ).

Is there any way i can get these values inside a method  without  using `@value` ( Injection)?

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
          <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:env.properties</value>

            </list>
          </property>
          <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
          <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
  </bean>
```

Comment: yes but why, the value injection is much nicer

Comment: @NimChimpsky, i have around 10 methods in my class, and this value is required in just one method.
Should i define it as class level and let spring inject it at the time this class is instantiated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could alternatively autowire in a properties bean :

```
<!-- creates a java.util.Properties instance with values loaded from the supplied location -->
<util:properties id="properties" location="classpath:/environment.properties"/>
```

Or alternatively do a `getBean()` of that from within you method.

But stick with `@value` , its slick, simple, and EASY TO TEST.

Comment: Nim you are correct and the implementation you suggested will work fine if i switch to this util schema.
But is there some way to read it using the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer based configuration as i mentioned in the question.